# higher kinded type in typescript from fp-ts and URI

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, fp-ts

In fp-ts they have this workaround for higher kinded types:

```
export interface HKT<URI, A> {
  readonly _URI: URI;
  readonly _A: A;
}
```

And it can be  used like this:

```
export interface Foldable<F> {
  readonly URI: F;
  reduce: <A, B>(fa: HKT<F, A>, b: B, f: (b: B, a: A) => B) => B;
}
```

What are the members `_URI` and what is `_A`?

Comment: is it clearer if written the following way? https://gist.github.com/jnizet/f8cc19c6e6c6f4937268cd5d095e851c.

Comment: `String` is a ground type, i.e. it has values. Let's denote ground types with `*`. `[a]` is a parameterized type, because it requires another ground type `a`. Consequently it has the form `* -> *`and is called a first-order type. Now a higher-order (or higher-kinded) type abstracts from the parameterized type `[]` and has the form `(* -> *) -> *`. `_URI` represents this first class paramterized type `(* -> *)` and `_A` represents the ground type `*`. That means an instance of `Foldable` requires a parameterized type (e.g. `[]`) and a ground type (e.g. `String`) to become a ground type itself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[This article written](https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts/blob/master/docs/guides/HKT.md) by the author of `fp-ts` explains very well,in combination with documentation on [TypeScript's union types](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/discriminated-unions.html).

`_A` is the type of the value in our HKT: `HKT<"Option", string> => Option<string>`. We'll see how mapping works in a bit.

`_URI` is the identifier for the HKT, for example [Option.ts](https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts/blob/master/src/Option.ts). It has 2 instances, `None` and `Some`, both of which have `"Option"` as their `_URI`.

[Taking a look at the usage of `F` in `Foldable`](https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts/blob/master/src/Foldable.ts#L19) we can see it's used in the `Type` type, along with `A`; `Type<F, A>`. Assume `F == "Option" & A == string` so `Type<F, A> == Type<"Option", string>`, which is very similar to `Option<string>`. Currently, we cannot pass a generic type to another generic as it's generic parameter: `<F,A>(fa: F<A>)` will not compile and this is the main problem.

To achieve `Type<"Option", string> => Option<string>`, there are several "mapping" interfaces (this is explained in the article). We can see this done for `Option` [here](https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts/blob/master/src/Option.ts#L19):

```
declare module './HKT' {
  interface URI2HKT<A> {
    Option: Option<A>
  }
}
```

The leftmost `Option` is a string key, the rightmost is the actual `Option` type, this is a normal record interface after all. Let's have a quick look at the definition of `Type`: `type Type<URI extends URIS, A> = URI2HKT<A>[URI]`.

`URI2HKIT` is a map from our `"Option"` to our actual `Option`. It's allowing is to pass 2 generic parameters to get back our value type wrapped in our higher kinded type, solving the generics issue mentioned earlier.

Comment: your answer has really helped.  One thing I do not get is why both `Some` and `None` have both a `_tag` property and a `_URI` property

Comment: They do separate jobs. `_tag` as explained is the tag used to distinguish between the individual types in the union. `_URI` is used to extend the `URIS` type from `/lib/HKT` https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts/blob/8ddf3b85af2e7f8b51cd7dda70be94564606916b/src/HKT.ts#L22.

You'll find a usage of `URIS` in `foldable`: https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts/blob/3f6023aaa35280c9753146437253cda762aa57fe/src/Foldable.ts#L22

Comment: More relevant to this is the `Type` type; `type Type<URI extends URIS, A> = URI2HKT<A>[URI];`. Without the `extends URIS`, we would not be able to use `URI` as the index type `URI2HKT<A>[URI]`.


`URI2HKT<A> = {"Option": Option<A>, ...}` which generates:
`URIS` = "Option" | ...;

Comment: This has the extra advantage of disallowing the mapping interface from having a different key to the `_URI`. If I do `{"Poption": Option}` then try to use `Type<"Poption", string>`, the resultant type will be `any` and not `Option`, as `"Poption"` isn't in `URIS`. (Though it's a shame it resolves to `any` and not a compile error).

Comment: i really can’t thank you enough.  i finally understand this

Comment: @MaxWillmo looks like a typescript bug (thanks for pointing out), I think I found a way to fix it though https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts/pull/529