# TypeScript interface mapped property generic type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to make this work

```js
interface ObjectPool<Ids, T> {
  pool: {
    [K in Ids]: T<K>;
  };
};

interface Player<Id> {
  id: Id;
}

let playerPool: ObjectPool<0 | 1 | 2, Player>;
```

so that

```js
playerPool[0].id === 0;
playerPool[1].id === 1;
playerPool[2].id === 2;
// playerPool[3] error
```

but typescript says I need a generic parameter at `Player` in `let playerPool: ObjectPool<0 | 1 | 2, Player>;` so I tried `let playerPool: ObjectPool<0 | 1 | 2, Player<_>>;` but that doesn't work too

Comment: Unfortunately, typescript ATM does not support higher order generics, i.e. what you're trying to do with `T<K>`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60008205/2967697

Comment: So your ObjectPool will only ever have a handful of items? If no, this approach doesn't scale. If yes, then this design is overkill. Can you explain the goal?

Comment: @Inigo I am creating a declaration file for a game. The player pool consists of 81 objects. The reason I use a generic type is because it can be used for other entities. The wall pool has 2000 objects.

Comment: So you intend do do something like `ObjectPool<0 | 1 | 2 | ... | 1999 | 2000, Wall>`? This is why I ask. That's not what static type checking is for.  It doesn't make sense.

Comment: What does `Wall` look like?  If the only generic piece is the `id` property and they all share it, it's possible that you could do something a little different like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WG69om) to get it to work.  But I agree with others that `0 | 1 | 2 | ... | 1999` is not going to be fun for you.  Even `0 | 1 | 2` is probably not great.  If you intend to loop over these things via numeric index, it'll be hard to treat the compiler that such an index will be of the narrowed union-of-numbers type instead of `number`.

Comment: I'm happy to write the above code up as an answer if it meets your needs, subject to caveats.  If there's something I'm missing about the question, though, please elaborate, preferably by [edit]ing the [mre] to demonstrate unsatisfied use cases.

Comment: @jcalz What you did with `{ id: K } & T }` is clever and works so do write is as an answer. I had already researched compile time generation of a range of numbers to use for types but nothing worked for the larger numbers, such as 2000. I understand what you guys are saying that it doesn't scale well but a 1 liner in js can generate all of it for me and then my ide can format it

Comment: @jcalz you are clearly a wizard with types, but does doing this make sense in any way (honest question)? Is it an abuse of static typing? Given TS being Turing Complete, we're gonna have to come up with meta static type checking soon. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write `T<K>`, then `T` needs to be some particular type operation (e.g., `type T<K> = ...` or `interface T<K> { ...`  or `class T<K> ...`).
There's no way to write `T<K>` where `T` is a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter.  That would require so-called *higher-kinded types*, of the sort requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213), and TypeScript has no direct support for that.

You could step back and try to think of exactly what you want to do, and if there's any way to represent it without needing higher kinded types.  If all you want is for `ObjectPool<P, T>` to have all property keys in `P`, and for each such key `K`, you want the property value to have an `id` property equal `K` in addition to some other properties specified by `T`, then you can separate out the `id` part in the definition so that `T` is just a regular type.  For example:

```
type ObjectPool<P extends PropertyKey, T> =
  { [K in P]: { id: K } & T };
```

Now you could define `Player` without making it generic:

```
interface Player {
  id: number,  // <-- you don't necessarily need this anymore
  name: string,
}
```

And now an `ObjectPool<0 | 1 | 2, Player>` should behave as desired:

```
function processPlayerPool(playerPool: ObjectPool<0 | 1 | 2, Player>) {
  playerPool[0].id === 0;
  playerPool[1].id === 1;
  playerPool[2].id === 2;
  playerPool[2].name;
  playerPool[3] // error
}
```

You can then define other types to use instead of `Player` and use them too:

```
interface Wall {
  location: string
  orientation: string
}

function processSmallWallPool(wallPool: ObjectPool<0 | 1, Wall>) {
  wallPool[0].location // okay
  wallPool[0].id === 0; // okay
  wallPool[1].orientation // okay
  wallPool[2] // error
}
```

---

You mentioned in a comment that you have 2,000 `Wall` objects in the pool.  That's a lot of elements to put in a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), but sure, you could do it (code generation is going to be easier than trying to convince the compiler to compute it):

```
// console.log("type WallIds = " + Array.from({ length: 2000 }, (_, i) => i).join(" | "));
type WallIds = 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | // ✂ SNIP! 
  | 1995 | 1996 | 1997 | 1998 | 1999
```

And then `ObjectPool<WallIds, Wall>` will also behave as desired:

```
function processWallPool(wallPool: ObjectPool<WallIds, Wall>) {
  wallPool[214].location
  wallPool[100].id // 100
  wallPool[1954].orientation
  wallPool[2021] // error
}
```

---

Please note though that the compiler really can't do much analysis on a union of numeric literals.  You might have more trouble than you expected with this. If you try to loop over the elements of `wallPool` with a numeric index `i`, the compiler will complain:

```
  for (let i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
    wallPool[i] // error! 
  //~~~~~~~~~~~ 
  // No index signature with a parameter of type 'number' 
  // was found on type 'ObjectPool<WallIds, Wall>'
  }
```

It has no idea that `i` is guaranteed to be a value of type `WallIds` in that loop.  It infers `number`, and you can't index into `wallPool` with any old `number`.  It needs to be a value of the `WallIds` union.  You could [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that `i` is a `WallIds`:

```
  for (let i = 0 as WallIds; i < 20000; i++) {
    wallPool[i] // no error, but, 20000 is an oopsie
  }
```

but, as shown above, you run into the problem that the compiler can't understand that `i++` might make `i` no longer a valid `WallIds`, as explained in [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14745#issuecomment-459881335) of [microsoft/TypeScript#14745](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14745).

If you're only ever going to be indexing into `WallPool` with a numeric literal value, like `wallPool[123]` or `wallPool[1987]`, then that's fine.  But as soon as you start storing and manipulating indices of type `number`, you will likely hit a roadblock with this approach.  It might still be worth it to you, but it's important to be aware of it.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwgY2ABQPYYDYB41QQAewEAdgCYDOUaAThpHaANIQgA0UAKgHxQBeAFBQoAbygBtFlACWZWgF0AXOLkVVMgL5QAZDyhaA3EKHzSdAGYBDZNDTZrICHXEioAeg-rVZAK4AtnAuXF5QZBjA4SgQVFTWdCDuZNYBEKpUwHTyAOYcQlqm5i42dlAA6tbY2G6iYbIa4YHBdKHeEVFkMXEJSaLYGMjWwLIYZBlZue4Y2eTAw6PjUJnZZDkFppZ+ZKiLUGAMdnEOTi6YOAAUYI7OdOfYqvBIqPe4AAxQAD5QAIxfUAAmLgnW68ACUtX2NzOWGwkjeigAdA1BAIBFA3iZRNdTndYZIfkiUWj0T8sVDcfdJACiRRUeiAeScbcqTTESk0kzoXicJIAMyKTzeFwMOgbIRbHYjMb7Q6xKgAZQCVWwlWq9wuAHcVfdHogUOhYe9-j8uGrsODIdr1fiEYiBkNpQowhgANZOdzW7BUu3EtEYoxCqBuj2iL1UwmImayOYLGUu919KDh-E0oMimbisLIMZUHAQe0YHIXABEoEgFRVAElqIIoCWoABqKAAQTodCciMsDACFwk2HIOWAAAtVAC3hPDFwLgB9LiyCECfgLxEIDDyUv-EtgsEmcvQc01mjoj7fP7fAH-Pn-AAs-wArP8AGz-ADs-wAHP8AJwm0+-c9fkvM9rzPO8z0fM8XzPd8zy-M9fwvf8AUAgFgMBUDAXAwFIMBaDAVgwF4MBRCoD5f8+UAvl0L5TC+WwvlcL5fC+UIvliL5Uib3-G9AJvdCb0wm9sJvXCb3wm9CJvYib1I+9-3vQD73Q+9MPvbD71w+98PvQj72I+9SKff8n0Ap90KfTCn2wp9cKffCn0Ip9iKfUjX3-V9ANfdDX0w19sNfXDX3w19CNfYjX1Ij9-w-QCP3Qj9MI-bCP1wj98I-QiP2Ij9SO-f9v0A790O-TDv2w79cO-fDv0I79iO-UifknM83kA5r0OazDmuw5rcOa-DmsI5riOaprmpNH52p+Tqfm6n5ep+fqfkGn5hp+Uafia8cTRQ3bOoBbqAV6gF+oBQaAWGgFRoBJryJNSiHs62iHt6xiHsG1iHtGziTW4v72v4v7uuEv7+vEv7hukv6mvkk1FPhzrVPh3rNPhwbdPh0bDJNYzcfa8zce66zcf6+zceG5zcaa9yTU8unOt8unesCunBtCunRsik1op59r4p57rkp5-r0p54bsp5pr8pNQrZc60rZd6yrZcG2rZdGxr-nHZC2u1t50PHTDx2w8dcPHfDx0I8diPHUiUOQqbtZm53jYW53zZW53rY2537Z2i89sDw3Du146w-N86w+t66w-t+6L0exPDZexPTfexPLa+xPbd+i9-vz1Cgfz43Qfz82Ifz63ofz+24YvBGG8N5GG9NtGG8tzGG9tnGLzxvvUMJvvjZJvvzfJvvrapvv7dpi96fnw2mfn03Wfny2Ofn23uYvXnd9QgXd+N4Xd-NsXd+tyXd-tmWLzlu-DcVu-TZVu-LfVu-ba175yIovWf4NleN4dE3gMTeExN4LE3hsTeBxN4pFKIUSdj-F2KC6LuxQUxL2KC2K+xQQggOZEg5EJoqHH+4dyFMSjuQtisdyEIITmRJOTCaKpyYQxDOTCWLZyYRxPOZEC4CKosXARdEy4CKYpXARbEa4CIQfXMijdFE0Rboohi7dFEsS7oojivcyL930VRIe+i6Kj30UxCe+i2LT30QgueZEF4OJosvBxDE14OJYpvBxHEd5kT3n4qih8-F0RPn4pi58-FsSvn4hBt8yL33iTRJ+8SGKv3iSxD+8SOLfygNxHi-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-SalQn6S0hE-Selon6TknEwySkGUiuSYZDSaTDI6UyYZAyOTjImQKcZCygrvjGRshU-d4rj1OSlceoysrTJmRaaZKy7TTJ2S6aZJyvTTJGUIeZMyBqoDmSsuM8ydkpnmScrM8yRlGGWTMg639bDLI2U4ZZByPDLIuX4dZEyfrf0iOslZcR1k7JSOsk5WR1kjIKNsmZeNv7VG2Rsho2yDltG2Rcno+yJlc2-uMfZKyZj7J2UsfZJyNj7JGXsY5Mydbf0uMcjZdxjkHJeMci5XxzkTI9t-UE5yVlQnOTshE5yTlonOSMnE1yZlZ2-uSa5GyaTXIOUya5FyOT3IeQKe5Hye6oDuQCke7zJ7-NhXPf5tysrPJeRaZ5Py7TPJBS6Z5MKvTPJuUId5LyP7vJ+XGd5IKUzvJhVmd5NyjDfJeRg75Py9E3ycN8iFHhvkIr8P8h5LD-kfKCTfOI-yQUpH+TCrI-ybkFGBS8tRwKfl1Jvg0YFEK2jAoRT0cFDynHgo+Usm+MxwUgqWOCmFGxwU3L2NCl5KToU-L+TfO40KIUvGhQir48KHkNPhR8olN8oTwpBQieFMK0TwpuTiZFLylnIp+XKm+NJkUQqZMihFHJ0UYoFOiglLz0UUp+eihlap3xoo5TqTj2VsU4otNikldpsU0pdNillXpsUoqEPinFH98UkrjPimlKZ8UsqzPilFRhiU4owcSklKrOPOGJQyjwxKOV+HJRilh5KCUOs4-EclNKUjkpZVkclKKCjUpxWo6lJKk2ccaNShlbRqUcp6PSjFTj6UErrZx2Y9KaVLHpSyjY9KUV7GZTilJzKSULs4-cZlDKXjMo5V8dlGKGnsoJTezj0J2U0oROyllaJ2UopxNynFSzuUkrg5x2k3KGVMm5Ryjk-KBUCn5RKl5-KFU-P5RqtjqA+UGr4-b7KwqRUWmFTKu0wqVUumFTqr0wqeVCHFSKj+4qZVxnFSqlM4qdVZnFTyow0qRUYOlTKqL9vnDSo1R4aVBq-DyoFSw+VEqyv2-iPKlVKR5U6qyPKnlBRlUirUcqmVE37eNFKoaptFKoGo9FqoCpONqoSond28zFqoqpLFqo6obFqo8p7FaoiopNaoypg9293FaoaovFaoGpfF6oCoNN6oSpE929Ql6oqoIl6o6pol6o8o4lGoipLNGoyoi9280lGoapMlGoGoclmoWpfgJx2oJxOoJxuoJxeoJx+oJxBoJxhoJxRoJwmo2p-xmomldCZC5o-x2ldClCuldC1DeldCtDCEOopCf0Oo5DxkOolCpkOo1DZkOotDGEuopCYMuo5CD8uolDmI-weEuoND+EeodDQEpCREeo5DxEeolCpEeo1DZEeotCFE+opDqM+o5D-8+olDtI-xtE+oNC9EBpojOMBoZDYCBoFDbI-xLEBo1CbEBotD7EhopCpMho5C8CholDgo-wvEhoNDfERpoiNMRoZCaCRoFDUo-wIkRo1DokRotC4kxopDLMxo5DeCxolDqo-xMkxoNDRCxDJoCkpoikAIvMrjFo-MrjVo28rjNou8ppZV3jpoWl3j5pjCpplozCpp1pLCppxobCZppp7CZp5onCZplpXCZp1oPCZpxpvC5ppo-C5p5pAi5ploQizw5p1p2JJpIiFodCFppo4iFp5pEiFploUiFp1p0iFpxosilpppcilp5oCilplpiiCTSilpNoKiVpyTqiVpZo6iVpFpGiCTmiVp1o2iVpxpOi1ppoei1p5p+i1plohiCSRi1pNpxiNpySpiNpZpZiNpFoFiCSliNp1pViNpxoNitppptitp5o9itplpDiCTjitpNpRCdZdpLjxwDpbiTYQyzoAsZpnibYQztoPiUJ2oUIDpDCzwUITolpdozCUIrpLCUJtobC0IUz7C0IjonC0IzpXC0IroPC0JtpvDDoUy-DDojpAjDozp8SgIwjDobpIjjodDjoUy4jjojpEjjozoUjjorp0jjptosjToUzcjTojoCjTozp+SgJSjToboKjzohzqjzoDo6jzoTpZSgJmjzoro2jzptpOjLoUyejLojp+jLozo9SgIRjLobpxjrohypjroDpZjroTobSgIljrorpVjrptoNjboUztjbojo9jbozpfSgJjjbobpRDf4HpLjyJnpbjyI3oHjyJPpnjyIfo3jEEHo9DKJnp0zfhKI3psyQIzDKJhpKIfotonodDqJ2pqJnpRk5onDqJ+pqJPpLonofpboHpvDaJBK-DaJupaI3pOEsTPowjaIfpIj6J+KsM5o4j6JVLEj6IJKUj6IuL0j6I7osjGJBLcjGJVKCjGIJKtzcSuL9IHoKjmJ+LqjmJno6jmI3oLy5pmjmIuK2jmI7pOjWJBKejWJVL+jWIJLPzCSuLwoHpxj2J+Kpj2JnpZj2I3pwK5olj2IuLVj2I7oNjOJBLtjOJVK9jOIJKMK5pjjOIfpRC8k-pLjuJOoSlerepuJwYYzuIoZgsySmpeIdDeJAZvjeIQZjDeJwYzDeIoZLDeJpqbDBk-p7D+IQYnD+JwZXD+IoYPD+JprvDFlgYBq2FqThqNLNlgYoZiSwJIj9k-pDLhIBq78FpEjzkvrBorkvrRpbkwZZqlE6SBrVE6ThqNE6TgbSjvkwZpqDEFpqjxIBq6jxJhqwrxJgbHI-o2iYVIZZrHFGSBqXFGThr3FGTgaRisVIZpr-EFopjpIBrZjpJhrSrpJgbMo-pVjqUYZZqEkWSBrkkWThq0kWTgbjjOUYZYZxClpLj+V4Zbj5JUYHj5IMZnj5JsY3jFIdD5V4ZvilVTbUY2LfhFIMY1pTbsZeKIIbC9VEYkYRLjVEZ+plIMZpKnbsY5KIJvC7V4Y-DVJupnUQ6vbuyuThpPUQ7YZBElpDL1IkY-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-J2o2tmYQnEjutmZ2YGGyn0jBs6YsiRspnGZYbAoWYEaZspmOmBGdSaZ0bgo+njE1o6jgoWYwrgp2Y5HdmuZXI6ZOjjsLnGZqbQoWY6brsLmOm9G1pxjHtOY+mF7woQnl7PtOZ2YbGynVj-s6YNigdQXGZJbIoWYZaodQWOmfGynRCEceZLjkdUWhYH6TTRYYzooJZJroompYodCic+ZOpSc+ZeoKc+ZBpqc+ZRo6ceYbDGcmXyWRL4oqXSnzTaXKnzSGW0GNpvCBdBZyX7rEoqWNKJdBYJZiHBWiXE7kp+Y4jkohZEi1ceYUjNcNWGX864Isj9cRZyXYbUoqWEbzcRYJY1nUoiX0b0p+Ydn0ohYzENowr0paWTn0oGXzm4JOi-dxZyXqbMoqW6aw9xYJYXnMoiXWbsp+YF7sohZl6U8eYlj09k2GWt64INjc8pZyXJbcoqWZbS8pYJZEWnTpZlb8p2o69ZZbjG8a3+oW8a3hoO8a3pYPje9ZZviB9O3lY0nCo1ZMnfhCpNZHah2bCZ95YFYRLiplYuXio1ZeXipNYBXSodDt9ZY-C98N3lYNLj8N3m3ZXSppZE7yoq24jypupyplZM6EIUiX8lZNZdWh2siv9ZZcjf833lYEagC33m21nKppZ0bqoq2dnqpL3nWEDVY1YTnqpNZvWh3OjMDZYeicDkPlY6bCDkPm2XnappZWb6oq2F76pL3l76CNY1ZAWAzNYM2h2NiODZZtjuCGPlYZaBCGPm3S3GpvxNhthdgZQDhBh5RzQNQUwcA9RnhDQcBcBDxqAzQVRLQxBPQdRUwFokQHQ4wyAlObReQxDaQgwxCtPvR8RvSbwkRoxYwnRDPWQDZCR0x2xMx3BLAZgoALgBwohZA6xMQ5AoBcBAQJwvPZBGxGwIRFPRAwxlPeRZBBQwgMw6AABCdwOobwAAOQwDkEoGIGWFkByBSGAD8DoGgE1FkBHCgGsH2ASFSAgAsGDEsCgH3CgAAHJ-AggXAGvkxrAaAnPtg6QZR6uGungDRXgZOqA5PqheAGv3BChRAnPXBXOqvvOTxSuaBhvAwPPfOdYJxVuguQvEv2vtO4QougwIhCB7PWgoA4A-BgAuANuPhZAaBrAFAsAwAqAYxJvxRTAgA)

Comment: Thank you for turning your comment into an extensive answer. Everything you said in the second half of your answer is completely valid. The problem is, I don't own the game. I am writing a declaration file for it and so it has to be as the developers made it. The code I have to work with is also obfuscated but the variable names dont change between updates

Comment: And how bad would it be if you just wrote `type ObjectPool<T> = Record<number, T & {id: number}>` or  `type ObjectPool<T> = Record<number, (T & {id: number}) | undefined>`?  I suspect it comes down to how often you index into an object pool with a numeric literal (so a developer writes `pool[123]`) as opposed to a nonliteral expression  (like `pool[i]` where `i` is `number` or even `keyof typeof pool`).

Comment: " I suspect it comes down to how often you index into an object pool with a numeric literal (so a developer writes pool[123]) as opposed to a nonliteral expression (like pool[i] where i is number or even keyof typeof pool)." The game has a global variable with the players id so its not uncommon to see `x.pool[id]` everywhere. Also, the game code is structured in such a way that to obtain a player you need to somehow get an id and then find the player in the pool