# Is it possible to create nested generics without explicit definition in typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am having trouble writing a type that applies one type to all the bottom level props of another type.

The purpose of this is to use create a type which can convert all bottom level props to Ref<T> for Vue 3.

```
// Start with some type T
type T = ...

// And a 'function' to apply, U
type U<T> = ...

// This needs to apply U to all bottom level properties of T
// ('bottom level' are all props who's type does not extend object)
type DeepApply<T,U> = ???
```

Example:

```
{
  a: string,
  b: number,
  c: {
    c1: number,
    c2: string
  }
}
```

Would become

```
{
  a: Ref<string>,
  b: Ref<number>,
  c: {
    c1: Ref<number>,
    c2: Ref<string>
  }
}
```

Here's my best shot but TS throws an error both when trying to give a generic its own generic arguments (U<T[P]>) and when trying to pass a type with generics as a generic without explicitly defining its generics (DeepApply<T, Ref>).

```
type DeepApply<T, U> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends object ? DeepUnion<T[P], U> : U<T[P]>;
};

type MyRefType = DeepApply<MyType, Ref>
```

Comment: How about leaving `U` away and using the type `type DeepApply<T> = { [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends object ? DeepApply<T[P]> : Ref<T[P]> }`

Comment: It's not directly possible to do this, sorry; there are some workarounds but nothing very nice.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60007436/2887218) and its answers.

Comment: Looks as if this is not likely to become a feature any time soon. Its a shame, this could open a lot of interesting doors in the typing system and eliminate a fair bit of repetition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a type is referenced, all it's generic parameters *must* be satisfied. Put another way, you can't pass a parameterized type without parameters to have it's parameters filled in later. There's just no syntax for that.

However, you can do it if you hardcode the `Ref` type. For example:

```
type DeepApplyRef<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends object ? DeepApplyRef<T[P]> : Ref<T[P]>;
};
```

I don't think a solution exists that is quite as dynamic as you want here, if your recursive type knows the type that it's wrapping things up with, then this does work just fine.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShBmAeAKgPigXigbygYwFcAnIiAO2AC4pkoBfAKAdEigBEIIwBBMMAGxBwkaTDgZQoAbQAKUAJZkoAawggA9vBoBdaslnaoEAB7ByAEwDOUdQCMAVhDzAoAfnacefQcJQH01L76MtqoANwMdBHM4NDIEJYuWBxcvAJCCIjYElAAhtSJRIoA5gA0ObbUZAQAtrYQROWSeNTZks0AjFW19Y05zQBMBcBFZMU5jHSoTAzmTvy5pPjqZIlQZol6CcDM2wB0uXuEJOQuAPRnUIUlu4lHRx1HxKQUUBdQ1XUNQA)

Comment: That's too bad, I'd love to see an analog to higher order functions in the TS typing system. Thank you for your suggestion though, hardcoding Ref will get the job done.