# TypeScript: typing a ramda pipe expression

Tags: typescript, ramda.js

I'm trying to type a return value of a `pipe` expression from `ramda`. The reason I'm doing this, is because the `filter` function from ramda gets the wrong inferred type, here is the related [issue](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/25581). So what I need is to return the correct type `string[]` instead of `Dictionary<string>`.

```js
const enumToArrayArrow = pipe(values, filter(isString));
```

When I'm writing it as a normal function declaration it's working fine, but it's a little bit verbose and I also have to pass the argument to the curried function returned by `pipe`.

```js
function enumToArray<T extends object, K extends keyof T>(enumValue: T) {
    return pipe<T[], Array<T[K]>, string[]>(values, filter(isString))(enumValue);
}
```

Is it possible to type the `pipe` expression in the first code snippet above?

[image: Edit gracious-bhaskara-w1ot9l]

Comment: I believe this is impossible for now, as what you're requesting is seem to be HKT, which has been discussed several times before, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60007436/higher-order-type-functions-in-typescript).

Comment: While Ramda is [working on](https://github.com/orgs/ramda/projects/3) bringing the type definitions in-house, there is only so much that can be done unless and until Typescript [supports Higher-Kinded Types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213).

Comment: Thank you both for the valuable input!!