# How to take return the type of method of other method?

Tags: typescript

I am doing an ORM multi-database support, and have this context, this code works but on the method select of schema is returned instance of Select, but I would like to return SqliteSelect

Lib ORM

```
class Model {
  id?: number;
}

abstract class Schema<A extends Adapter, M extends Model>{

  abstract Model: new () => M;
  abstract modelName: string;
  readonly adapter: A;

  constructor(adapter: A) {
    this.adapter = adapter;
  }

  newModel(): M {
    return new this.Model();
  }

  select(): Select<M> {
    return this.adapter.getSelect<M>(this);
  }
}

abstract class Select<M extends Model>{

  getAll(): M[] {
    return []
  }
}

interface Adapter {

  getSelect<M extends Model>(schema: Schema<this, M>): Select<M>;
}
```

Adapter for sqlite

```
class SqliteSelect<M extends Model> extends Select<M>{
}

class SqliteAdapter implements Adapter {

  protected db?: Database;

  getSelect<M extends Model>(schema: Schema<this, M>): SqliteSelect<M> {
    return new SqliteSelect<M>();
  }
}
```

App place

```
class MonkeyModel extends Model{}

class MonkeySchema<A extends Adapter> extends Schema<A, MonkeyModel>{

  Model: new () => MonkeyModel = MonkeyModel;
  modelName: string = 'monkeys'
}

let ZooAdapter = new SqliteAdapter();
let schemaMonkey = new MonkeySchema<SqliteAdapter>(ZooAdapter);

let select = schemaMonkey.select();
```

**`type of select = Select<MonkeyModel>, but I would like that the return was SqliteSelect<MonkeyModel>`**

I tried to change the Adapter interface to receive the type SqliteSelect when it was extended in SqliteAdapter

```
interface Adapter2<S extends Select> {

  getSelect<M extends Model>(schema: Schema<this, M>): S<M>;
}

//it dosen't work because the SqliteSelect wants M type
class SqliteAdapter2 implements Adapter<SqliteSelect> {

  protected db?: Database;

  getSelect<M extends Model>(schema: Schema<this, M>): SqliteSelect<M> {
    return new SqliteSelect<M>();
  }
}
```

I won't pass all classes to Schema when instance it, because are many classes, like it:

```
let schemaMonkey = new Schema<SqliteAdapter, SqliteSelect, SqliteInsert, SqliteCreate, SqliteUpdate, SqliteDelete, SqliteTruncate>(zooAdapter);
```

Is it possible to take the SqliteSelect type from SqliteAdapter to put on the return of schema.select?

Comment: It would be nice if you could pare the example code down a bit more.  But in any case, this is currently a general limitation of TS.  There are no *higher kinded types* as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213).  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60007436/higher-order-type-functions-in-typescript Does that fully address your question or am I missing something?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).