# TS - losing typesafety

Tags: typescript

I have following code here:

```
type Picks = Record<
  string,
  {
    a: () => any
    b: () => any
  }
>

const picks = {
  first: {
    a: () => 'something',
    b: () => 'something else'
  },
  second: {
    a: () => 1,
    b: () => 33
  }
}

const pickSomething = <T extends Picks>(picks: T) =>
  <K extends keyof T>(key: K): ReturnType<T[K]['b']> => {
    const { a, b } = picks[key]
    return a() + b()
  }

const someOtherPickFunction =
  <K, R>(fn: (key: K) => R) =>
    (key: K) => {
      const result = fn(key)
      return result
    }
```

and this works without problems:

```
const test = someOtherPickFunction(pickSomething(picks))('a')
```

however, if i would like to do something like this:

```
const mainFn = <T extends Picks>(picks: T) => someOtherPickFunction(pickSomething(picks))

mainFn(picks)
```

i now lose type inference. is there a way to solve this?

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/C4TwDgpgBACglgYwNYGcoF4oCUIIPYBOAJgDwCwAUFFCsAXAHYDmANJdQN7vVQCGAXFAAUASgwA+PgxDdqAI0GiJUmVSgBfSuMqV8DWlDCJUGKFzUAzOAVqDzPPorHpJAchR4AthGAALRkyubGryTsruXj7+zFAQADYoEK7c6sHUiXpEdrKOws6SAIxpPAp5ygDM5SmUmhS6ePrAhsYAypF+AaYkACqxAB7AEAxEaPDIKOJCRuOC3fncJADS-YPDaEgQIHgWUN2TGyCCiyKCOMAArgQM3eAQPQDaiwC6965yrk+SLmY5egYcfBYUDkGlM01Q9wOTxyBB8lwYfCUAGpgaJqnUKH8mh5vAB5PwQAhjJAAMXODAQwDgDQwC0WQKwkwsDEUByO+Ww8xCwjZUGOynsDigWKgsJQ5ziTUwzKEBxEOWosIuV1FEHFkpytXqjSgnl4jBJCMwPRWQxGsGMEymltmHJxEHxvkJxLJFKpDWtyDa3g6zE9qBE8oxeoNDH9KDEAHpI1AGHgoIwLIShghoEA)

Comment: "i now lose type inference" How? What type are you getting? What type are you expecting?

Comment: I'm getting `ReturnType['a']['b']`. i'm expecting `string` or `number`

Answer (score 0):

realized i have to explicitly set the return type:

```
const mainFn = <T extends Picks>(picks: T)
  : ReturnType<ReturnType<
  typeof someOtherPickFunction<keyof T, ReturnType<typeof pickSomething<T>>>>> => someOtherPickFunction(pickSomething(picks))
```

don't know whether there exist a smoother way of doing this but this works