# Generic type that applies a passed generic type?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jsdoc

#### Question

Is there a general way to implement a generic type that takes a type `T` and a generic type `G<>` and outputs the former passed into the latter `G<T>`?

### Goal

```js
/**
 * @template G, T
 * @typedef {G<T>} Transform<G,T>
 */

/** 
 * @typedef {Transform<Array, string>} StringArray
 * @typedef {Transform<Promise, string>} StringPromise
 */
```

This doesn't seem to work unfortunately.

#### Limited functionality

What does work is this, but it needs the possible generic types to be specified.

```js
/**
 * @template G, T
 * @typedef {G extends Promise ? Promise<T> : G extends Array ? Array<T> : unkown } Transform<G,T>
 */

/** 
 * @typedef {Transform<Array, string>} StringArray 
 * @typedef {Transform<Promise, string>} StringPromise 
 */
```

Comment: Is this Typescript ir Javascript+JSDoc question?

Comment: There is no direct support for *higher kinded types* in TypeScript; see the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60007436/higher-order-type-functions-in-typescript) for more information; some of the answers there mention the various workarounds/approaches to simulating them (although I still think they are too cumbersome to recommend in general)

Comment: @jcalz Thank you. I hope this moves forward somehow given how old the issue is